# React js Dom elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am new in react js and have a one question about DOM elements. I have a table in my component. On mouse over I want to highlight corresponding cell and row . I want to have an coordinates of that element. For example on hovering 3-th cell of 4-th row I want to have result as `{ r-4, c-3 }`. I do not want use jquery for finding position of rows. How can I reach to that result?

Comment: You can highlight the current row and cell using just CSS; there's no need to determine the coordinates. If you do need them, just add a `hover` listener to each cell as you create them.

Comment: The problem is that I need to send to server the coordinates.

Comment: Sounds like you just want an `onmouseover` handler that passes the coordinates somewhere. Where are you having trouble? Can you show some code?

Comment: add your code in fiddle or codepen or code sandbox

Comment: you can use pure js in componentDidMount

Comment: @samankhademi here is jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/Boris996/cwrs9L8t/3/

Comment: What is the problem about negative votes ? )

Answer (score 1):

you can add js native code in `componentDidMount` and use `e.target.cellIndex` for `td` and `e.target.rowIndex` for `row`

```
const tds = window.document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0; i<= tds.length -1;i++){
    tds[i].addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
    console.log(`cell ${e.target.cellIndex +1}` , `Row : ${e.target.parentElement.rowIndex + 1}`);
  })
}
```

live demo in react at codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJdjJW?editors=1010

hope i can help you

Comment: ok so if it was your answer please press the tick beside this answer to make it the main answer for the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, react does not work with DOM, it renders the DOM itself, so the jquery can not helps you, if you want to do such things, I suggest you search more about react [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), you can handle it by using ref and onclicks, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you should not touch the DOM yourself, that would kill the purpose of react

instead, your event listeners should be expressed in your component and react would handle them

internally, this means that react will call addEventListener and removeEventListener when necessary among other useful optmizations

first your data should be structured as a nested array
and then map over your rows and cells

thanks to the power of Array.prototype.map, you will have access to the indexes of the rows and cells

```
rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
    <div>
      {row.map((cell, cellIndex) => (
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(`you clicked on ${rowIndex}, ${cellIndex}`)
          }}
        >
          {cell}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ))
```

here is working example in codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/6zw42m4pxw

Comment: Thank you for attention. In my mind your example will help me. I couldn't vote

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of `onMouseOver`, `setState`, and dynamic styling:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            x: null,
            y: null
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>User is hovering over ({this.state.x}, {this.state.y})</p>
                <table>
                    {(new Array(10)).fill().map((_, y) => (
                        <tr>
                            {(new Array(10).fill().map((_, x) => (
                                <td
                                onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({x,y})}
                                style={{backgroundColor: (this.state.x==x || this.state.y==y) ? 'red' : 'grey'}}
                                ></td>
                            )))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render((<App/>), document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: 'collapse'
}

td {
  padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped. can I write code for highlighting specific items based on this logic. For example hovering on (3,4) coordinates not to highlight all the row or cell. Instead highlight only (3,4), (3,3), (3,2). thank you in advance